# Where is the "Privacy" menu for the "WP Robots Txt" plugin?

Tags: robots.txt

I want to be able to update the robots.txt for my WordPress site.

From brief research it looks like the "WP Robots Txt" plugin is the easiest. However the tutorials eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JY9A5OqHTvw say that I need to look under the "Settings" -> "Privacy" menu in order to update the text for the robots.txt.

Even though the plugin installed without errors, this menu does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

From WordPress v3.5 this menu has moved to "Settings" -> "Reading" From here you can easily update the text of your robots.txt file.

See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-robots-txt-privacy-doesnt-appear-in-settings for further info